# Haskell's `putChar` doesn't print anything if used with `threadDelay` > 1 sec

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I'm trying to write a simple program which outputs `xoxoxoxoxoooxoxxxxoxoo` string.

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent

loop :: Char -> IO ()
loop c = do
  putChar c
  threadDelay 1000000 -- 1 second
  loop c

main = do
  forkIO $ loop 'x'
  forkIO $ loop 'o'
  getChar
```

If I use big values (`1` second or `0.1` second) for `threadDelay` it doesn't print anything until I press any key (and program prints output and exits obviously).

However, if I use small values like `10` it prints large chunks of chars to the terminal.

Two questions arise.

First. Is it a terminal buffering issue? Or Haskell buffers IO somehow? Can I disable it?

Second. Can I use such technique for writing a game loop for a server with multiple game rooms with independently calculated states? Like you create a room for 2 players starting a fight, `forkIO` thread does all math and 30 times per second reports updated state back to players TCP sockets.

Could you also recommend the best thread communication pattern for such task? STM? I used to use Erlangs actors for similar tasks in the past. But seems people try to avoid actors in Haskell.

Comment: Yes, it is likely a buffering issue. The function you want is [`hSetBuffer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering). When you set a very small delay, your terminal is likely going to flush the buffer when the characters exceed the length of a single line (which is very fast for 10ms delay). I'm not sure what the 2nd questions means - what 'technique' do you refer to? Of course you can do arbitrary computation inside a thread started with `forkIO`, just like you can do so in the main thread. The last question (library recommendation) is off topic.

Comment: Try `hFlush stdout` after the `putChar`

Comment: @user2407038, the question doesn't ask about libraries. It asks about "thread communication pattern[s]".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is a buffering issue. Import `System.IO`, then add `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` to the beginning of `main` to fix it. Yes, you can use `forkIO` for concurrency. Don't forget to compile with `-threaded` and run your program with `+RTS -N` or similar if you want more than one OS thread to be available.